# How to call a List<DataTable>

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I'm looking over some code that was given to me to try and learn how one would load an excel spreadsheet into a `DataTable`. I have gotten that part to work, or at least I think it worked because it didn't abend. What I would like to do now is check to see if the DataTable was populated. The problem I am having is having the `Form` recognize the List from the Class.

Here is the code for my Class:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
class Class1
{
    public List<DataTable> ImportExcel(string FileName)
    {
        List<DataTable> _dataTables = new List<DataTable>();
        string _ConnectionString = string.Empty;
        string _Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileName);

        if (_Extension.Equals(".xls", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            _ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        }

        else if (_Extension.Equals(".xlsx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            _ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;";
        }

        DataTable dataTable = null;
        var count = 0;
        using (OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(_ConnectionString, FileName)))
        {
            oleDbConnection.Open();
            DataTable dbSchema = oleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables_Info, null);
            foreach (DataRow item in dbSchema.Rows)
            {
                using (OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    oleDbCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection;
                    oleDbCommand.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", item["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());

                    using (OleDbDataAdapter oleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        if (count < 3)
                        {
                            oleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand = oleDbCommand;
                            dataTable = new DataTable(item["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
                            oleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                            _dataTables.Add(dataTable);
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return _dataTables;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code for my Form:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = textBox1.Text;
        Class1 ext = new Class1();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a file extension");
        else
            ext.ImportExcel(fileName);
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried some things such as:

`List<DataTable> ldt = new Class1.ImportExcel`
`ListBox.Items.Add(ext.ImportExcel._dataTables)`

Along with some other things but none seem to work. I've googled up on how to call a `List` and nothings worked. I've called a `DataTable` before in a previous exercise but I couldn't tailor that to this code.  If there is some documentation that would assist me, or if I am close please push me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the question.  Particularly your use of the word 'call' does not seem correct to me.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are want to verify that your data populated successfully?  Or are you saying wanting to display the DataTable on the UI?

Comment: New to c# so I may not be using the correct lingo. I guess to clear things up, hopefully, the end result would be for me to have whats in the `DataTable` show up in the ListBox1. So in my head I need to "call" the `method` in which the DataTable is being populated.

Comment: I guess both, since if it was populated successfully it would show up in the ListBox1

Comment: You could always just use LinqToExcel to read from an Excel sheet: http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following ways you can use a list with any type of key:

```
List<String> Test = new List<String>();

Test.Add("TEST");
Test.Add("Test");

Console.WriteLine(Test[0]); // TEST
Console.WriteLine(Test[1]); // Test

char[] t = Test[0].ToCharArray();
```

To get some values on a list by searching the name or id, use the following way:

```
List<String> Test = new List<String>();

Test.Add("TEST");
Test.Add("Test");

string arry = Test.Where(x => x[0] == 'T').ToArray()[0];

Console.WriteLine(arry);
```

I haven't tried the datatable stuffs yet, But you can easily use these methods, Foreach statement is also great for some stuffs:

```
List<String> Test = new List<String>();

Test.Add("TEST");
Test.Add("Test");

foreach (string str in Test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, but if the List was being populated in the `Form` then I wouldnt have a problem getting the values from it. The List<DataTable> is in a class and am having a problem getting it in the Form.

Comment: @user2405778 Add `public static` to the first of your List, like: `public static List<DataTable> MyList = new List<DataTable>();`

Comment: Okay, I'll mess around with this for awhile. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) library to easily import your data.

---

ImportData.cs File

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")] 
public class ImportedData
{ 
    public string DropDownValue;
    public string DropDownText;
}
```

---

Form1 File

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string fileName = textBox1.Text;
    FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(ImportedData));
    // To Read Use:
    ImportedData[] customData = engine.ReadFile(fileName) as ImportedData[];

    // let's say you named your ListBox as listBox1
    listBox1.DataSource = customData;
    listBox1.DataTextField = "DropDownText";
    listBox1.DataValueField = "DropDownValue";
    listBox1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

---

If you don't want to use the FileHelper library, then:

```
 ListBox.DataSource = ldt;
 ListBox.DataBind();
```